# What does 就那样吧 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conversation

This is a conversation with my friend and she started to live in Moscow recently.

> I: 你莫斯科生活怎么样？
>
> She: 就那样吧

Pleco showed 那样 means "like" or "that kind", but in this case that doesn't make sense. I feel this is an idiom, but what does 就那样吧 mean in this context?

Comment: 就 may indicate wish to evade the question, "it is the way it is"

Comment: cf.＂汉语水平考试词典＂ 就［义１５］出现在相同成分中间，表示马马虎虎、容忍的态度（used between 2 alike words  to indicate condonement, perfunctory (if it's lost, it's lost):他爱说～让他说吧，我无所谓｜十块钱～十块钱吧，我买了。

Comment: 就那样吧: Just like that (what you think). 就那样吧 = 就和一般人没什么区别 or 就和你想的差不多, or **not that bad, not that good also**.

Comment: documentary evidence for below answer:   就那样吧，什么意思？https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/751912603617081204.html 最佳答案

女的说就那样吧，表示还是可以的。

Comment: "Just so so" .....

Comment: 意思是：和平常一樣，as usual；沒什麼特別的，nothing is special。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

就那样吧 is the same as 也就那样吧 in this case, which is a colloquial phrase, not an idiom.

It means: "just so-so", "it's just ok", "things going just like that".

It conveys her life in Moscow is not that good, or not as good as she — or someone else — expected.

You can take it as a shortened form of 生活就那样吧 or 生活也就那样吧.

Comment: Is there also 就这样吧? Any difference?

Comment: difference: see dictionaries, bkrs：就这样吧 do so; OK 暂且就这样吧。That will do for the present 暂时就这样吧。Leave it at that.ichacha：    so be it
    that's all time is up
    well all right 暂且就这样吧    that will do for the present...

Comment: @Blaszard, as user6065 indicated, 就这样吧 means 'so be it'.

Answer (score 0):

就 = just,
那样 = that kind = like that,
吧 is used just to finish the sentence,
Just like that, it means just so-so.

Answer (score -1):

> 就那样吧 has two means.

1.It means Just so so .
2.the words mean:something happaned is that.

Answer (score -1):

There are two senses in which it's used:

1. modesty:  it implies [something is] very general, or ordinary.
2. "just like that" and we needn't worry about it anymore.

Comment: in you sense, it means just so so,  barely satisfied. @Blaszard

Answer (score -1):

Just so so.

Not good, not bad.

Most of the time, this means people are not satisfied with something.

Answer (score -2):

It literary translates to:

就  那   样  吧 =
*"And that like !"* or *"Thus that like !"*

where 吧 is a kind of "!" sign.

So in human language it should be something like this: "And like that!" or "Aaaand it's like that. Do it!" or "Thus (it should) be like that!"